# What happens to the file handle when file is removed?

Tags: python, file, error-handling

I executed the following:

```
Fo=open ('file','w')
Fo.close()

Import os 
Os. Remove('file')

Print fo.read()
```

On executing, I get: ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

1) this means python still recognises the file handle even after the file is deleted. Why does it do this?

2) why did I get ValueError?

3) in what cases do we get IOError?

Edit: I want to make myself clearer:
*why did I get a value error for operating on a closed file?*
We generally get ValueError on things like this:

```
int('abc')
```

Where the wrong value is given. Operating on a closed file seems like something related with IO. Could anyone clarify?

Answer (score 1):

1. No, it means that the `file` object still exists.
2. The `file` itself is no longer appropriate for most operations, hence it is/has an invalid value.
3. None. The file is closed, so no I/O can occur.

Comment: For 1) yeah, that was my question. Why does the file object still exist even after the file was deleted? ( I used 'file handle' instead) what is the purpose of still keeping it? And 3) could you give me an example where IOError occurs?

Comment: 1) Because the `file` object is still referenced by the variable `Fo`. It has nothing to do with "purpose" but with object lifecycle. You may check the `closed` attribute before using it further

Comment: 3) Your hard disk failing to access a 512bytes sector when a `read` operation is performed

Comment: @mementum, thanks! This might be asking too much but when you are free, could you give me the exact code snippet that will give overflow error?